# How can i know if the Daemon was stopped from a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, apache-commons-daemon

My Daemon create and runs a function on a different thread this function runs many other functions. I want to check before each function if the Daemon was closed and if not then i will perform the function.
How can i know if the Daemon was stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other thread, you have to get the thread instance and then call:

```
thread.isAlive()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Daemon extends Thread()
{
  private boolean started;
  public void Daemon() {
    started = false;
  }
  public void run() {
    started = true;
    // rest of your code.
  }

  public boolean isStoped() {
    return started && !isAlive();
  }
}
```

Use `isStoped()` to know when your thread has been stoped. `isAlive()` alone is not enough because a thread which has not been started will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and is a daemon thread if and only if the creating thread is a **daemon**.

If you don't know if the thread is daemon or not then use `isDaemon`,

> **isDaemon**
>
> public final boolean isDaemon()
>
> Tests if this thread is a daemon thread.
>
> Returns:
>   true if this thread is a daemon thread; false otherwise.

Then you can ask the Thread for its current status by calling:

```
Thread.State ts = thread.getState();
```

and you should get one of the follwing:

A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:

- **NEW**
  A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- **RUNNABLE**
  A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- **BLOCKED**
  A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
- **WAITING**
  A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- **TIMED_WAITING**
  A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
- **TERMINATED**
  A thread that has exited is in this state.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon()